# Why is window.name cached?

Tags: javascript

in a programming challenge I recently took part in I had to use the `window.name` property to store / manipulate data. I found out that, when you change this property, it persists through page refreshes (although not when opening a new page with the same URL).

The only information I could find was that this is known and even used by some frameworks as data storage, but I would be interested in the why (as in why is window.name persistent? Any historical reasons?) and the how (which rules are there of when the `window.name` is kept between page changes and when it is discarded?).

Apparently, my Google-fu is not strong enough to find the answers to these questions (there is not even a mention of it on the MDN page!) so I hope that maybe you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of it is that the window object is persistent throughout the lifetime of a tab, and represents the window that is loading different HTML documents.

Each tab contains its own `window` object, which is why even when you navigate to/from different pages the window object is persistent, whereas if you check on a different tab the `window.name` will be different.

When opening different html pages, most of them do not override the `window.name` property, and it is completely optional. If nothing else is manipulating it, it will be what you leave it as. Most pages only touch on manipulating the `window.document` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Named windows are used as link targets, for one:

```
<a href="example.html" target="some_page">some page</a>
```

The link will open in a new window once, and in the same window if it still exists on subsequent clicks, with the window’s name being how it’s targeted.

The second argument of `window.open` is also a window name.

```
window.open('example.html', 'some_page');
```

You can try it out in your browser across unrelated websites; in one tab’s console, set `window.name = 'test';` and in the other, use `window.open('https://example.com/', 'test');`. (You may have to let it through a pop-up blocker.) The unrelated tab should navigate to https://example.com/.